# Is there any difference between the terms userland and userspace?

Tags: terminology

Sometimes I read about the term userland and sometimes userspace.

From Wikipedia, it is said that userland is referring userspace:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userland

Is there any difference between the terms userland and userspace?

Comment: As far as I understand, they refer to the same thing.

Comment: One is a themepark for kernel developers

Answer (score 1):

Taken from yourdictionary.com

> **Userland:** (computing, informal) A conceptual space outside the kernel in which a user's applications can run without the risk of damage to the operating system.
>
> **Userspace:** (computing) The area of memory used for a user's applications, etc., as opposed to that reserved for the operating system